# How to block temporarily comments from specific IP address?

Tags: 7, comments

Can we block specific IP address for a period of time and block posting comments from that IP address for this period of time? 
Only posting comments, not viewing pages.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this module but you can check [Comment IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_ip) module.

> This module displays a comments IP address in the comment overview
>   page and allows you the option to "Delete the selected comments and
>   block their IP's" from the comment overview dropdown list.

Comment: The problem is that I must not block the IP from viewing content. I must block it only for posting comments, and then after a set period of time unblock it.